# MATLAB preallocating space to a while loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, memory

I have been unable to find sufficient examples that will help me with my problem of preallocating space to my loop.

I have the following code for my while loop:

```
Time = [];
Pressure = [];

ii = 1;

while ii<=20000

Pressure_Data = fread(fileID, 2);
Pressure = [Pressure;Pressure_Data];
Time_Data = fread(fileID, 8);
Time = [Time;Time_Data];

ii = ii + 1;

end
```

I then get the warning squiggle under Pressure_Data and Time-Data `"Appears to change size on every loop iteration. Consider preallocating for speed."`

So I would like to preallocate space because at the moment the time to read the file and store the data takes some time.

My attempt thus far:

```
Time = zeros(160000,1);
Pressure = zeros(40000,1);
```

However I just get an array of zeros and not the read and stored values I require

Comment: What is changing inside the loop except the variable jj?

Comment: @freude the `fread` reads more info from file `fileID`.

Comment: Hm well, 2 bytes are read from a data file followed by 8 bytes and this is repeated until the number stated "20000" has been reached. So each time 2 bytes and 8 bytes are read this results in a different result.... Or as @Shai has just mentioned :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current Pressure- and Time-values are appended to the existing arrays:

```
Pressure = [Pressure;Pressure_Data];
Time = [Time;Time_Data];
```

What you actually want is to write the current value to the correct position in the array. This is done by

```
Pressure(2*ii-1 : 2*ii) = Pressure_Data;
Time(8*ii-7 : 8*ii) = Time_Data;
```

The indexes are made up as follows: In the first iteration (`ii=1`), we write to `Pressure(1 : 2)` and `Time(1 : 8)`. In the second iteration (`ii=2`), we write to `Pressure(3 : 4)` and `Time(9 : 16)`, and so on.

Another small input: as you let `ii` go from 1 to 20000, you can also use a for loop:

```
for ii=1:20000
    Pressure(2*ii-1 : 2*ii) = fread(fileID, 2);
    Time(8*ii-7 : 8*ii) = fread(fileID, 8);
end
```